# Google Maps fetching transit information based on Stop ID

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have got names and Stop IDs of several of TTC stops (Toronto). Based on the Stop ID, I want to get additional information on the stop.

E.g. Based on the attached picture, if I input the Stop ID 2123, I want the information of mode of transport (Light Rail) and the route (505).

I have tried a lot, but am not able to find the right API in Google Maps and Google Transit to fetch the data. Can someone please point me to the right direction? I can't do it manually through Google Maps web interface, as there are 5000+ Stop Ids.

Look forward to some guidance. TIA

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no public facing endpoint to get this information via Google Maps API at the moment. I've seen a feature request in the Google issue tracker to make this information available (5 stars currently):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827961

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote.