# Google API for bus stop lines

Tags: json, api, google-places-api

I'm creating a smart public transport app and trying to get the data about bus stops from Google. I can easily get the closest bus stations, bus I also need to see which busses (bus lines) are available in those bus stops.

Google says there are some ***transit_details*** in the Places API, but I don't see how I can get them after getting the closest bus stations.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TransitDetails

this is an object of the request for getting closes bus stops:

```
{

    geometry: {
    location: {
        lat: 46.77649719999999,
        lng: 23.6280244
    },
    viewport: {
        northeast: {
            lat: 46.7778461802915,
            lng: 23.6293733802915
        },
        southwest: {
            lat: 46.7751482197085,
            lng: 23.6266754197085
        }
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png",
    id: "86e66fd8a89d6aec0b9cc59e7ca14c08e6d92076",
    name: "Strada Siretului",
    place_id: "ChIJQZ3PtGwMSUcRAYCfYNJak48",
    rating: 5,
    reference: "CmRSAAAAjklKtNRZscODDtwcPoR5L79IdJoMyMFprmOyz3rEY2-0gPoTMhFPP7FGjO7n6T53hSjrs38DIxcqXcXOnT8OLSIrb4Q05lI6BdEOWMp_A0zkmSLtvHZqmFouvS5sMQ-yEhCxv-VOUO5PGIFOqZcmbOCPGhQRot14-a4Ng1CJYkwD35VBi5djfA",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
        "bus_station",
        "transit_station",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Cluj-Napoca"
}
```

How can I see the bus lines available for the station?

[Google Maps bus lines at bus stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilj6p.png)

Comment: There is a feature request for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47768080/5140781

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Comment: No, I guess the request is not public yet.